# CLI helper in Rust

Tags: rust, child-process

This is my first hands-on experience with Rust. The program actually works and I really like how it functions. I'm just very interested in what code improvements I could do.

I wrote an application in Rust to help me manage my php environments. 
The binary can be run like:

```
timpack-cli composer install # run composer install
timpack-cli php72 composer install # run composer install with 'php72'
```

In the future I want to add in detetection to check what php version should be used.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::env;
use std::process::{exit, Command, Output, Stdio};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let input_arguments: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let interpreters = ["php", "php70", "php71", "php72"];
    let mut interpreter = String::new();
    let mut binary = String::new();

    // Create a hashmap for the command aliases.
    let mut aliases = HashMap::new();
    aliases.insert(string("m1"), string("n98-magerun"));
    aliases.insert(string("m2"), string("n98-magerun2"));
    aliases.insert(string("cc"), string("composer"));

    // Start from index one, since first element is the executed binary, which we don't need right now.
    for i in 1..input_arguments.len() {
        let arg: &str = &input_arguments[i];

        if i == 1 {
            if interpreters.contains(&arg) {
                interpreter = arg.to_string();
            } else  {
                binary = arg.to_string();
            }
        }

        if i == 2 && !interpreter.is_empty() {
            binary = arg.to_string();
            break;
        }
    }

    // Fail fast, no binary to run.
    if binary.is_empty() {
        println!("No binary given.");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Resolve alias usage if necessary.
    if aliases.contains_key(&binary) {
        binary = aliases.get(&binary).unwrap().to_string();
    }

    let mut executable = binary;
    let mut command_arguments_index = 2;
    let mut command_arguments = Vec::new();

    // Prepare command execution if binary needs to be run with interpreter.
    if !interpreter.is_empty() {
        let output = Command::new("which")
                .arg(executable)
                .output()
                .expect("Execution of 'which' failed.");

        command_arguments.push(output_to_string(output));

        executable = interpreter;
        command_arguments_index += 1;
    }

    // Push all remaining stdin args to the new command arguments
    for i in command_arguments_index..input_arguments.len() {
        &command_arguments.push(input_arguments[i].to_owned());
    }

    // Run command and wait for status.
    let status = Command::new(executable)
              .args(command_arguments)
              .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
              .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
              .stderr(Stdio::inherit())
              .status()
              .expect("Failed to execute command");

    // Exit program with status code of command execution.
    exit(status.code().unwrap());
}

/**
 * Create String from str.
 */
fn string(value: &str) -> String {
    return value.to_owned();
}

/**
 * Get string from Output type.
 *
 * @TODO: What about stderr?
 */
fn output_to_string(output: Output) -> String {
    return String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap().trim().to_string();
}
```

Also, it's [available on Github](https://github.com/tdgroot/timpack-cli/tree/077af180bde618c82ea9f5d96ef9f6ad24ddd880), if that's easier.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things pop out at me.

1. Prefer `Iterators‘ over “raw” indexing for loops.

   Instead of this

   > ```
   > for i in 1..input_arguments.len()
   > ```

   You can just loop over the arguments.

   ```
   for argument in input_arguments
   ```
2. There’s already a `to_string()` method on `&str`. No need to define it yourself.